# Generating $n$ numbers whose random subsum equals zero

Tags: number-theory, summation

Let $k$ and $n$ two positive integers with $k<n$. Is it possible to generate $n$ numbers ($\neq 0 $) whose any subsum of $k$ numbers equals zero?

Comment: Well, you could take $n$ $0's$.  Otherwise no.  (take any non-zero element $n_1$. Take any sum that does not contain it and swap an element in it of the opposite sign or $0$, or just $\neq n_1$, for $n_1$).

Comment: @lulu Thanks. For $k=n-1$ that can't work, but what about particular values of $k$? Say $k=n-2$.

Comment: I never said $k=n-1$.  My construction works for any $k<n$.